# foreach contracts in client app from app.config file

Tags: .net, wcf, app-config

I have a question about: how can I use "foreach"  the service's namespaces in client application?

So, I have web.config file in my service.
Here client section:

```
<client>
      <endpoint address="http://nail:81/raj/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
      <endpoint address="http://www.xxx.ru:81/upd/Service1.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService11"
        contract="ServiceReference2.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />
    </client>
```

In my client app I use it like this:

```
updater.ServiceReference1.Service1Client myclient = new updater.ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
```

The problem: In future, I will have more than 50 references in web.config (on my service).
And I don't want to write 50 code lines like this.

Thank's a lot!

Comment: I don't understand which is the point of iterating service clients' namespaces in order to avoid instantiating them 50 times.

Even if you iterate these namespaces, what advantage you'd get for this? Are you going to call an operation of all services in a single point?

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you don't need this. 

Whenever you need to call a service operation, you may need to create a particular instance of some service client.

Comment: I have one client application and 50 computers with 50 services. All of these services are connecting to my computer. If I want to use all of them, I must create 50 client objects. But I want use something like 'foreach' for creation client's objects and use them. Maybe there are other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, I dont need in 50 objects for 50 service references. In App.config, in client section I can write :

```
endpoint address=""
```

And from my client code, in circle, I write :

```
EndpointAddress endp = new EndpointAddress("some_ip_adress");
                            myclient.Endpoint.Address = endp;
```

That's all.

Thanks **Matías Fidemraizer** for advice!

Answer (score 2):

Answering to one of your comments (and your question, of course):

> I have one client application and 50 computers with 50 services. All
>   of these services are connecting to my computer. If I want to use all
>   of them, I must create 50 client objects. But I want use something
>   like 'foreach' for creation client's objects and use them. Maybe there
>   are other way?

Honestly I don't find any advantage on instantiating 50 times your service clients and have these objects up to use them compared to "***creating a variable somewhere you want to call a service operation, creating an instance of some service client***".

Really you're going to have 50 objects in memory, for what? It's a waste of memory and after all your goal is someway useless.

It's like saying, I've 50 business manager in my business layer and I want to preload them... but wait, why don't I instantiate everyone separately when code needs it?

Maybe I'm absolutely misunderstanding your goal, but it seems you want to overcomplicate your scenario to arrive to the same point.

Comment: The endpoint names in app.config (client section) must be different, so I have objects with different names. If I need to use all of these endpoints, I must create corresponding objects. Or I write 50 code lines , or I just (any way) create 'foreach' and use my circle. Is that possible?

Comment: Before answering to your question, please answer to another one: do you need to create an instance of these 50 objects in a single point? I mean, do you've some method that must get them all there?

Answer (score 0):

What you have in the config is the configuration of the service and endpoints, which is NOT what you are instantiating.

You instantiate `updater.ServiceReference1.Service1Client`, which is a proxy class generated by the WSDL tool. The only way to make this dynamic is to use Reflection to load the types in that namespace.